# Can I use a Vista installation disk to repair a Windows 8.1 system?

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, windows-vista

Someone I know is having a problem with booting their Windows 8/8.1 system. I'm assuming the boot /fixboot (and maybe boot /fixmbr) command will be able to solve the problem, but I don't have a Windows 8 disk myself. The only Windows installation disk I have is that of Vista. So I was just wondering whether I should be able to use it to repair this friends Windows 8 system? Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: Both the Vista installation disk and the system I'm attempting to repair are 64-bit so there should be no compatibility issue. I should also add that I don't currently have the machine I'm talking about, it will be brought to me in a couple of days so I thought I'd ask here just to be sure.

Comment: Most of the tools should work, so yes. So what do you plan to do? What exactly are you trying to repair?

Comment: The WinRE version that Windows Vista would use is an entirely different version then the WinRE version that Windows 8.1 uses.  No; You cannot use a WIndows Vista installation to repair Windows 8.1 installation.  Just use a [Windows 8.1](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) Installation disk to repair the installation.

Comment: @Ramhound depends on the type of repair, this disc will load all tools, I have done it. They clearly stated they do not have the needed W8 disc.

Comment: https://mega.nz/#F!WoYRiaTa!6s3X-sBYtlQqLPXFmv9pzg

Comment: I suppose my comment stims from the fact, I have never actually been sucessful in repairing an Windows installation with the WinRE and have found that nearly 100% of the time if my system is not booting its because of the HDD that has failed.

Comment: @Moab I'm planning to run the commands "bootrec /fixboot" and "bootrec /fixmbr". I don't know if the latter is necessary but why not.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use vista installation disk to repair Windows 8.1 system. But you can use Advanced Startup option.

steps for advanced stratup:

1. Tap or click on the **Start butto**n.

**Note:** *In Windows 8, **Swipe from the right** to open the charms bar. Tap or click **Change PC settings**. Choose **Update and recovery** from the list on the left (or **General** prior to Windows 8.1), then choose **Recovery**. Skip down to Step 5.*

2. Tap or click on **Settings**.
3. Tap or click on the **Update & security** icon, near the bottom of the window.
4. Choose **Recovery** from the list of options on the left of the UPDATE & SECURITY window.
5. Locate Advanced startup, at the bottom of the list of options on your right.
6. Tap or click on **Restart now**.
7. Wait through the Please wait message until Advanced Startup Options opens.